# Length inequalities for a Convex Polygon

Tags: geometry

We have a convex polygon with length of three sides given as $4,5,12$ and no other information. We need to find the range of the fourth side. The only inequality I'm aware of is largest length will be less than sum of length of other three. This comes out to the range of $x$ as $3$ to $21$. Is there any other inequality that can be applied to narrow down the range.

Comment: No. Nothing further can be deduced given your information.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there is a convex polygon $P1$  whose fourth side has length 21, and another one $P2$ whose fourth side has length 3.

Suppose you had some clever proof showing that the range of values for the fourth side was smaller than $[3,21]$. Then $P1$ and $P2$ would be counter-examples showing that your proof must be wrong.

Comment: True. Convinced. Thanks!